# Could promptness be considered a red flag by recruiters?

Tags: interviewing, communication, recruitment

As the title indicates, I am wondering whether *promptness* can be considered a red flag (e.g. unprofessional, offensive, etc) by a recuiter?

By promptness, I mean for instance:

- replying quickly to emails, e.g. within a few hours
- when asked for possible interview dates, proposing several dates in the coming week including some in the coming days
- sending a remainder email one week after the last contact with the recruiter
- etc

From my point of view, I think (hope) it comes across as dynamism. But could it cause a negative feeling from the recruiter's point of view ?

I ask because the recruiters I have been in contact with often do not reply or provide feedback with the same promptness, which I am not sure how to interpret...

Comment: You're overthinking this. Most likely they have dozens of emails going in and out constantly, while you probably have only a couple or so, and wouldn't notice how fast or slow you write back to them even if it was written in the subject title ...

Comment: OK, this is what I have been telling me, but the confirmation is welcome.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you the recruiter?

Comment: @JeffO no, in the context of this question, I would be the candidate.

Comment: all of your described behaviour would, to me, appear as normal, professional behaviour - so, no... not red flags

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing that you outline in your question would be a red flag, and I say this as someone who was an agency recruiter for nearly twelve years. On the contrary: I was trained to use things like speed of response and willingness to schedule interviews as tests of commitment with candidates, to see whether they are serious about job hunting. So I wouldn't worry about it: a polite follow-up email after a week of no contact is totally fine, and replying quickly to set up interviews just makes the recruiter's life easier. No need to worry about either of those things.

It sounds like you're getting interviews though, which is great! If a recruiter doesn't contact you with interview feedback it's most often for one of these reasons:

1. They haven't had any feedback from the client. A quick phone call to say "sorry, no news yet" should happen, but this is the sort of thing that, unfortunately, often/usually gets overlooked.
2. They have bad feedback, and haven't got round to telling you yet: happens a lot, especially with recruiters who don't like breaking bad news.

(It's also possible that you are runner-up to another candidate, and the recruiter wants to keep you lined up as a possibility in case the other person turns down the job, but in this case you would usually get a few phone calls to keep you interested.)

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and the insider's insights!

Comment: So you intentionally were told to drag your feet to see if the candidates would respond to you? I would be careful with this advice when dealing with highly-skilled employees or when the economy is doing well. My guess is you don't work in the medical profession. I would never give the impression that the candidate needs me more than I need him.

Comment: @JeffO No, wouldn't intentionally drag your feet. More testing the reverse: a candidate who takes ages to reply, isn't available for interview etc. is less likely to be serious about job searching. Of course it's not definitive, but it's an indicator.

Comment: I've known SO many recruitment consultants who can't/dislike/hate/avoid/evade giving bad news; point #2 is very common.